# Replace number in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, substring

I have some data in Oracle, actually, I want to replace the first 7 digits with 0

> 3420962813221908
> 34210628211699686

the result I wanted will be

> 0813221908
> 08211699686

I'm trying to use `replace` and `substr`, but it turned out no result.

Comment: Do you want to have number as output or varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to use `substr` to cut away the first seven characters, and contact `0` with it:

```sql
SELECT '0' || SUBSTR(mycolumn, 8) FROM mytable
```